# Set decimal separator of org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Spinner

Tags: java, swt, separator

**EDIT:** It is impossible because the swt `Spinner` widget gets the decimal separator directly from the OS and NOT from the Java VM.

I have a german application which uses per default `,` as a decimal separator. I would like to change all the decimal separator's uses in the application from `,`  to `.` without changing the locale since the application still needs to be german regarding everything else.

The spinners are created like that:

```
Spinner spanWidthSpinner = new Spinner(parent, SWT.BORDER);
spanWidthSpinner.setValues(0, 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 2, 100, 1000);
```

I start my application like that: (Note that it doesn't matter if I set the target language to `en` or `de`, the separator is always a `,`.

```
-os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl}
```

I tried to set the following which had no effect at all:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().setDecimalSeparator('.');
```

I also tried to set the following local: `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));` This also always showed a `,` as decimal separator instead of a `.`.

Basically I want my `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Spinner` instances to show `.` instead of `,` as decimal separator.

How can I achieve that? I would prefere a global setting but having to set it on individual widgets is okay too.

Comment: Where do your spinners get the data they display?

Comment: The spinners are created lke that: spanWidthSpinner = new Spinner(parent, SWT.BORDER);
spanWidthSpinner.setValues(0, 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 2, 100, 1000); I added that information to my question.

Comment: Which `Locale` are you using in the application?

Comment: I didn't set any Locale. I'm starting the application with: -os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl} . The application is started on a german computer.

Comment: Looking at the source of `Spinner` the decimal separator used seems to always come from the native locale settings

Comment: That's what I figured also but I refuse to belive it's impossible to replace the separator anyways? The separator gets its decimal separator like that: String getDecimalSeparator () {
 TCHAR tchar = new TCHAR (getCodePage (), 4);
 int size = OS.GetLocaleInfo (OS.LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, OS.LOCALE_SDECIMAL, tchar, 4);
 return size != 0 ? tchar.toString (0, size - 1) : ".";
}

Comment: I tired manually setting a local but it didn't help. Still only a ","

Comment: So sad but true: Greg is right. It's impossible to replace the decimal separator of the Spinner widget since it's getting retrieved from the OS and not form the Java VM. Looks like I will have to use a different widget or implement my own Spinner.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: this has been discussed in [SWT bug 103127](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=103127).

Answer (score 1):

Since getDecimalSeparator method has default access modifier, it is impossible to change its behaviour through inheritance. In our company, we had the exact same need and we had to change the source code of the plugin that contains Spinner class. We changed Spinner class' source code so that we could override getDecimalSeperator method (made it public) and repacked the jar(e.g. org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.xxx.jar) then put it under delta-pack plugins directory. Afterwards whenever a product was built, the changed plugin was used.